# "Syntax error in input" when SWIGging Boost.Geometry?

Tags: python, c++, boost, swig, boost-geometry

Error Message:

```
Error: Syntax error in input(1)
```

My Swig file:

```
%module interfaces

%{
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> Point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point, true, false> Polygon;
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%template(MultiPolygon) std::vector<Polygon>;
%template(pgon) Polygon;
```

If I comment out the last line, it compiles

```
// %template(pgon) Polygon;
```

I've been re-reading the swig section on templates and I can't understand at all what's wrong.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: and what's the error message...?

Comment: `Polygon` isn't a template anymore, it's a concrete type, so why do you need the `%template(pgon)`? SWIG probably has some other syntax to create an alias if you want `Polygon` to be called `pgon` in the Python world.

Comment: @Praetorian Isn't Polygon a templated class still?  When reading the documentation for Swig, I had the impression that any class with <> in it's definition needed to be wrapped in %template()

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Error: Syntax error in input(1).

Comment: `polygon` is a class template, `polygon<Point, true, false>`, or an alias for it, isn't a template anymore, you've specialized it by providing all the template arguments, it's a real type now.

Comment: Put the error message _in the question_. Should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `Polygon` is a typedef or alias for a specialization you still need to use `%template` with the actual template you care about, e.g.:

```
%template(pgon) polygon<Point, true, false>;
```

You'll also need to show SWIG enough of the definition/declaration of the types involved for it to figure out what's going on and use the right types.

Thus the smallest complete interface file that behaves how you want is:

```
%module poly

%{
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
%}

%inline %{
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> Point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point, true, false> Polygon;
%}

namespace boost {
namespace geometry {
namespace model {
template<typename P, bool CW, bool CL> struct polygon {};
namespace d2 {
template <typename T> struct point_xy {};
}
}
}
}

%include "std_vector.i"
%template(Point) boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
%template(pgon) boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point, true, false>;
%template(MultiPolygon) std::vector<Polygon>;
```

This is because SWIG needs to know a definition of every type it wraps as well as just the `%template` directive. You also need to make the typedefs you write visible to both SWIG and the C++ compiler, which I did with `%inline` to avoid repeating them.